# Why does tarfile.extractall ignore errors by default?

Tags: python, permissions, tarfile

Python's [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile-objects) module ignores errors during extraction **by default**, unless `errorlevel` is set to either `1` or `2` (or `debug` to `1` if only error messages need to be printed).

Try doing a `mkdir /tmp/foo && sudo chown root /tmp/foo && chmod a-w /tmp/foo` and using `tarfile` to extract a .tar.gz file over `/tmp/foo` -- you will see that your Python code threw no exceptions at all. The files would *not* have been extracted over `/tmp/foo` which still is an empty directory.

Why this behavior? Who/what benefits from this **default** behavior? In other words, just who/what would want to ignore, say, permissions errors when decompressing a tarfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, this nasty behavior is will be changed in Python 2.7 and 3.2. http://svn.python.org/view?view=rev&revision=76780 Apparently the reason for ignoring the errors before was to be more like GNU tar, which ignores errors.